# I need help translating a Chinese seal/stamp on a painting

Tags: translation, character-identification

I don't have the adequate knowledge or tools to translate the characters. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I know about sites like zdic.net and [Chinese character database](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php) that have data on anicent glyphs, but there's no search function based on that. So you'd need someone who can recognize the glyphs by sight...

Comment: [LINE dictionary](https://dict.naver.com/linedict/#/cnen/home) has the pen icon to let you search by drawing a character, if only there's a version of that for ancient glyphs.